# Is text classification fast enough for type ahead search?

Tags: machine-learning, text-classification

I'm working on designing a typeahead service that can be used to search for many different things. I was thinking about creating a text classification model to categorize these searches before actually making the search.

Here's an example of the result I'd want from the classification model.

Input

```
John Smith
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "likeliness": .6,
    "category": "car-name-typeahead-search"
  },
  {
    "likeliness": .9,
    "category": "person-name-typeahead-search"
  },
  {
    "likeliness": .1,
    "category": "vin-typeahead-search"
  },
  {
    "likeliness": .2,
    "category": "help-page"
  },
  {
    "likeliness": .2,
    "category": "faq-page"
  }
]
```

Then I'd take the categories that have a likeliness above some value and actually do the typeahead search. Also I'd return the results ordered by the likeliness rank.

We have been collecting data about people's searches and tracking what they were actually looking for so we should have the data needed to train a text classification model.

My question is can text classification models be fast enough to be used with a type ahead service and not be prohibitively expensive? Are there certain types of text classification algorithms that I should be looking at?

Comment: I'd suggest you don't do premature optimization. Design some realistic tests, measure performance and then decide.

Comment: I think modern search engines already incorporate similar techniques. But chances are the outcomes for most of the common inputs are already precomputed and cached for performance and only a small number of user inputs would really need to go through the ML model in real time.

Comment: What is your definition of fast enough? Also you did not mention where the classification model is running (on client side or you run the classification as another service so you need some RPC to communicate the result). Usually in modern serving framework (like tensorflow serving running on a standalone server), a standard text classification model based on shallow neural networks should have a latency under 1ms).

Comment: @greeness we want the typeahead response time to be less that 200ms total. The classification model will be server side. It sounds like text classification models are more than fast enough for our needs. If you add your answer I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually in modern serving framework (like [tensorflow serving](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving) running on a standalone server), a standard text classification model based on shallow neural networks should have a latency under 1ms). You can look for a model composed by:

- word embedding layer (up to millions of words in vocabulary)
- hidden layer (1-3)
- classification (up to thousands of categories)

If your expected response time is <= 200ms, you should not worry about the latency from the classification. In the worst case, 10ms is sufficient using the setup above.